# Evaluate integral of a series

Tags: functions, calculus-and-analysis, evaluation, series-expansion

I want to evaluate this integral, but it won't work. Does anyone knows why?

```
Remove["Global`*"]

dm = (M/(2 π a)) a ;

i[ϵ_] = 1/(a Sqrt[1 - 2 (ϵ) Cos[θ] + (ϵ)^2]);
i1[ϵ_] = Series[i[ϵ], {ϵ, 0, 1}];
invertdist[r_] = i1[a/r];

ϕ[r_] = -Integrate[G dm invertdist[r], {θ, 0, 2  π}]
```

Comment: There are two errors in your code: functions are defined with `:=` and `Series` requires a symbol as a variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing wrong with your code is that [`Series`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Series.html) doesn't return an expression suitable for evaluation at specific values of the expansion variable. You first have to convert the `SeriesData` object to a normal expression using `Normal`. This is the only change needed:

```
i1[ϵ_] = Normal[Series[i[ϵ], {ϵ, 0, 1}]];
```

With this, the integration works as expected:

```
ϕ[r_] = -Integrate[G dm invertdist[r], {θ, 0, 2 Pi}]

(* ==> -((G M)/a) *)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I now know how to use the "Normal".

Comment: @Lawerance: if you are satisfied with the answer you received from Jens (and it seems you are), then please Accept his answer.